# Deploying 2012 SSRS Report to Azure SSRS? o365 SharePoint Online options?

Tags: azure, reporting-services, sharepoint-2013

I'm looking at the ssrs deployment guide on the Azure site and it says to specify a 2008 r2 target? is ssrs on Azure not 2012? can I deploy 2012 SSRS reports? Also it suggest I download report builder 3.0, do i need that if I plan to install 2012 BI ? Is there even a 2012 BI install for Visual Studio 2012? Ideally I'd like to build and deploy SSRS 2012 reports.

Also, Can SSRS2012 consume SharePoint Online List Sources?  Any plans for SP Integrated SSRS in o365/SharePoint 2013 Online?

And finally, we are looking for way to move from SP 2007 On prem, but we have 500 SSRS 2005 reports in SharePoint we need to somehow deliver through SharePoint.. any good shorterm option while MS catches up with this critical integration need? Right now we have SharePoint clients that don't want to go to the Cloud without their SSRS Reports.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding SQL 2012 compatibility I can't find anything that explicitly confirms 2012 compatibility, but based on the "Guidelines and Limitations" info Azure SQL Reporting is compatible with SQL Server Data Tools, which are the new version of SQL tools released with SQL Server 2012. That page also contains a link to download Report Builder, which links to the 2012 version.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg430132.aspx#Tools

Note that Azure SQL Reporting only supports Native Mode report server (not Sharepoint Integrated) and also **only supports Windows Azure SQL databases as a data source**.

Comment: Thank You. I too read that. Eagerly waiting for more options and will go out of my way to prove Azure reports currently can't consume SPO List sources.

Comment: Would you know if Report Builder 3.0 can be used to deploy and maintain SSRS reports in SharePoint 2007?

Comment: Yes, to my knowledge you can launch and use report builder from either a native or sharepoint integrated report server.

Comment: Looks like the document on the link provided has now been removed. Does that mean that this feature is no longer supported?